# Combobox data transfer

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have created a firemonkey app for windows with many components-editbox, label, rectangles, layout and a database in sqllite. I want to transfer combobox data to database table but failed. Anyone help how to transfer data from combobox to sqllite database.

I have tried these -

1. `FDQue.FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString :=cbCN.Items.Text;`
2. `FDQue.FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString :=cbCN.Selected.Text;`

Both syntax are not success. First syntax store only first item of combobox into database. Second gives "Access Violation error"

Comment: Please add a language tag. Is this Delphi? It is neither valid VB nor valid C#. Of what type is `FDQue`? You probably need something like this (just a shot in the dark): `FDQue.FieldByName("CustomerName").Value = cbCN.SelectedItem;`. FireMonkey is not winforms.

Comment: Delphi, FDQue is query

Comment: You nedd to append each "line" into the query component.

Use `FDQue.Append` before setting the data value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following code example:

`FDQue.FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := cbCN.Items[cbCN.ItemIndex];`

It will store the selected ComboBox item into the field `CustomerName`.

Also don't forget to call `FDQue.Post` after you have set all necessary field values to finally save them to the database!

Comment: Using `cbCN.Selected.Text` will work just fine provided that `cbCN.Selected` is not `nil`, so check for that beforhand. If you use `cbCN.Items[cbCN.ItemIndex]` then you have to check that `ItemIndex` is not `-1` before using it with `Items[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using `ComboBox.Selected.Text`, because `Selected` here doesn't always mean that this item was actually selected, whereas `ComboBox.ItemIndex` always does.

`Selected` also indicates that this item was the last to be hovered over in the dropdown list.

So, your option would be:

```
if (cbCN.ItemIndex <> -1) // Check if ComboBox has a selected item
    FDQue.FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString := cbCN.Items[cbCN.ItemIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to read the selected text and store it in your DB. This can be done quite easily.

1. If your table (or query or whatever) is on a different form (such as a datamodule), add the datamodule to your form's uses clause.
2. Go to the `Livebindings` property of your combobox and click on the arrow.
3. `Bind Visually` will pop up. Click on it.
4. The `Livebindings Designer` should then come up with all your components and the tables on your datamodule.
5. Now all you need to do is locate the correct field and drag a line to the `selected text` property of your combobox.

I always use `TFDTable`s but see no reason it wouldn't work just as well with a `TFDQuery`.